# make an LED blink on rpi2 in assembly

Tags: led, raspberry-pi, assembly

I am trying to make an LED blink on assembly on my raspberry pi 2 model B to debug some startup code.
However I don't see anything blink. Could someone tell me what I am forgetting?

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;
;;@ BLINK LED
;;


main:
                       @ Configure the LED GPIO pin for output

    ldr r0,=0x3f200000  @ Load r0 with hexadecimal number: 0x3f200000 (Raspberry Pi 2)
    mov r1,#1           @ Move decimal number 1 to r1
    lsl r1,#21          @ Logical shift left the value in r1 by 21 places
    str r1,[r0,#16]      @ Store r1 in the address calculated by [r0 + 16]  (Raspberry Pi 2)
                        @ Turn the LED on
    mov r1, #1          @ Move decimal number 1 to r1
    lsl r1, #15         @ Logical shift left the value in r1 by 15 places
    str r1, [r0,#32]    @ Store r1 in the address calculated by [r0 + 32] (Raspberry Pi 2).
                        @ Now on pull-high pin (47) instead of pull-low pin (16), so write
                        @ to GPSET register instead of GPCLR.
   b main
loop$:
    b loop$             @ Branch to loop$
```

The entire startup code:

```
.extern system_init
.extern __bss_start
.extern __bss_end
.extern vFreeRTOS_ISR
.extern vPortYieldProcessor
.extern rpi_cpu_irq_disable
.extern main
    .section .init
    .globl _start
;; 
_start:
    ;@ All the following instruction should be read as:
    ;@ Load the address at symbol into the program counter.

    ldr pc,reset_handler        ;@  Processor Reset handler         -- we will have to force this on the raspi!
    ;@ Because this is the first instruction executed, of cause it causes an immediate branch into reset!

    ldr pc,undefined_handler    ;@  Undefined instruction handler   -- processors that don't have thumb can emulate thumb!
    ldr pc,swi_handler          ;@  Software interrupt / TRAP (SVC) -- system SVC handler for switching to kernel mode.
    ldr pc,prefetch_handler     ;@  Prefetch/abort handler.
    ldr pc,data_handler         ;@  Data abort handler/
    ldr pc,unused_handler       ;@  -- Historical from 26-bit addressing ARMs -- was invalid address handler.
    ldr pc,irq_handler          ;@  IRQ handler
    ldr pc,fiq_handler          ;@  Fast interrupt handler.

    ;@ Here we create an exception address table! This means that reset/hang/irq can be absolute addresses
reset_handler:      .word reset
undefined_handler:  .word undefined_instruction
swi_handler:        .word vPortYieldProcessor
prefetch_handler:   .word prefetch_abort
data_handler:       .word data_abort
unused_handler:     .word unused
irq_handler:        .word vFreeRTOS_ISR
fiq_handler:        .word fiq

reset:
    /* Disable IRQ & FIQ */
    cpsid if

    /* Check for HYP mode */
    mrs r0, cpsr_all    ;@move FROM coprocessor reg to ARM register Current Program Status Register
    and r0, r0, #0x1F
    mov r8, #0x1A
    cmp r0, r8
    beq overHyped ;@branch if equal als r0 en r8 gelijk zijn jump naar overHyped
    b continueBoot ;@branch(=jump)

overHyped: /* Get out of HYP mode */ ;@HYP = is een modus voor virtualization
    ldr r1, =continueBoot ;@load addres van continueBoot routine in R1
    msr ELR_hyp, r1     ;@ move ARM register to coprocessor register
    mrs r1, cpsr_all    
    and r1, r1, #0x1f   ;@ CPSR_MODE_MASK
    orr r1, r1, #0x13   ;@ CPSR_MODE_SUPERVISOR
    msr SPSR_hyp, r1
    eret                ;@return

continueBoot:
    ;@  In the reset handler, we need to copy our interrupt vector table to 0x0000, its currently at 0x8000

    mov r0,#0x8000                              ;@ Store the source pointer
    mov r1,#0x0000                              ;@ Store the destination pointer.

    ;@  Here we copy the branching instructions
    ldmia r0!,{r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9}         ;@ Load multiple values from indexed address.       ; Auto-increment R0
    stmia r1!,{r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9}         ;@ Store multiple values from the indexed address.  ; Auto-increment R1

    ;@  So the branches get the correct address we also need to copy our vector table!
    ldmia r0!,{r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9}         ;@ Load from 4*n of regs (8) as R0 is now incremented.
    stmia r1!,{r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9}         ;@ Store this extra set of data.


    ;@  Set up the various STACK pointers for different CPU modes
    ;@ (PSR_IRQ_MODE|PSR_FIQ_DIS|PSR_IRQ_DIS)
    mov r0,#0xD2
    msr cpsr_c,r0
    mov sp,#0x8000

    ;@ (PSR_FIQ_MODE|PSR_FIQ_DIS|PSR_IRQ_DIS)
    mov r0,#0xD1
    msr cpsr_c,r0
    mov sp,#0x4000

    ;@ (PSR_SVC_MODE|PSR_FIQ_DIS|PSR_IRQ_DIS)
    mov r0,#0xD3
    msr cpsr_c,r0
    mov sp,#0x8000000

    ldr r0, =__bss_start
    ldr r1, =__bss_end

    mov r2, #0

zero_loop:
    cmp     r0,r1
    it      lt
    strlt   r2,[r0], #4
    blt     zero_loop

    bl      rpi_cpu_irq_disable


    ;@  mov sp,#0x1000000
    b main                                  ;@ We're ready?? Lets start main execution!
    .section .text

undefined_instruction:
    b undefined_instruction

prefetch_abort:
    b prefetch_abort

data_abort:
    b data_abort

unused:
    b unused

fiq:
    b fiq

hang:
    b hang

.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr

.globl GET32
GET32:
    ldr r0,[r0]
    bx lr

.globl dummy
dummy:
    bx lr


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;
;;@ BLINK LED
;;


main:
                       @ Configure the LED GPIO pin for output

    ldr r0,=0x3f200000  @ Load r0 with hexadecimal number: 0x3f200000 (Raspberry Pi 2)
    mov r1,#1           @ Move decimal number 1 to r1
    lsl r1,#21          @ Logical shift left the value in r1 by 21 places
    str r1,[r0,#16]      @ Store r1 in the address calculated by [r0 + 16]  (Raspberry Pi 2)
                        @ Turn the LED on
    mov r1, #1          @ Move decimal number 1 to r1
    lsl r1, #15         @ Logical shift left the value in r1 by 15 places
    str r1, [r0,#32]    @ Store r1 in the address calculated by [r0 + 32] (Raspberry Pi 2).
                        @ Now on pull-high pin (47) instead of pull-low pin (16), so write
                        @ to GPSET register instead of GPCLR.
   b main
loop$:
    b loop$             @ Branch to loop$
```

Comment: I've not read your code, but one common problem is forgetting to delay long enough while the LED is both on *and* off. Do you see the LED as always on or always off?

Comment: Yea I would start by trying to turn it on solid first. Then throw a few million nops in otherwise the loop maybe to fast for human eyes. Just out of interest why assembly?

Comment: @RogerRowland well actually I didn't express myself correctly. The ACT led blinks continuously no matter what I do even when I comment my code. (yes, I am mahoma...)

Comment: @crowie  I didn't express myself correctly. The ACT led blinks continuously no matter what I do. Even when I comment my code. (yes, I am mahoma...) I am just not sure I use the correct addresses. My goal is just to make a pin or an LED toggle I don't really care which one. I write asm because the startup code I use was written in asm I just added the non-working LED blink part to debug a few things.

Comment: Ahh ok, well I avoid assembly like the plague (lol sorry just not my bag baby) but I had a quick look at the Broadcom BCM2835 peripherals manual. Apparantly the 2835 and 2836 architectures are supposed to be the same. There seems to be 1 address for GPSET0 (0x7e20001c) and 1 for GPSET1 (0x7e200020)

Comment: Which pin are you trying to set?

Comment: I think you have to write a 1 to the bit number that corresponds to the pin number ie for pin 5 you would write (1<<5) to the GPSET0 address

Comment: @crowie I am just trying to toggle any pin, doesn't matter which one.

Comment: @crowie what should I modify to get the example above working? The example above doesn't work with shift operations.

Comment: Like I said I'm no good at asm, just write a 1 to the correct GPSET register address to turn on pin 0 and the same to the CLR register address to turn it off